# VB NET + TextBox + Insert MySQL + Accent

Tags: mysql, vb.net, text

I have a problem. I try to insert the following text that finds it in a box text.

> Le développement durable (anglais*:*sustainable development, parfois
>   traduit par développement soutenable) est une nouvelle conception de
>   l'intérêt général, appliquée à la croissance économique et
>   reconsidérée à l'échelle mondiale afin de prendre en compte les
>   aspects environnementaux et sociaux d'une planète globalisée. Selon la
>   définition donnée dans le rapport de la Commission mondiale sur
>   l'environnement et le développement de l'Organisation des Nations
>   unies, dit rapport Brundtland, où cette expression est apparue pour la
>   première fois en 1987, le développement durable est un développement
>   qui répond aux besoins du présent sans compromettre la capacité des
>   générations futures à répondre à leurs propres besoins.

But I have a huge mysql error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'intérêt général, appliquée à la croissance économique et
>   reconsidérée' at line 1

What is wrong ? That my code. Thanks for the help.

```
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class TEXT
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As New MySqlCommand
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Dim a As New OpenFileDialog
    Private Sub TEXT_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("text.My.MySettings.textConnectionString").ToString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "insert into text (text) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
            MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados")
            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to escape the apostrophes in that text string. Imagine inserting a text like `Hi I'm jnevill`. Your sql string will look like: `insert into text (text) values ('Hi I'm jnevill');` And you can see the string terminates before it's ended.

Comment: You **need** to use SQL parameters

Comment: OK. I understand. But how I can do to remove this limitation. I see myself misreading long texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It's solve, with addparameters.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Imports System.Configuration

Public Class TEXT
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As New MySqlCommand
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Dim a As New OpenFileDialog
    Private Sub TEXT_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Text.My.MySettings.TextConnectionString").ToString)
    End Sub

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        COMMAND.Connection = MysqlConn
        COMMAND.CommandText = "INSERT INTO  text (text) Values (@Value1)"
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text), DBNull.Value, TextBox1.Text))
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados")
        'MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

probably the issue is that the text have a ' in it and this make your query concatenate in a incorrect way, to solve this you must add ''' for each ' that your text string has so the query could keep his correct form

Comment: OK. I understand. But how I can do to remove this limitation. I see myself misreading long texts.

Comment: an easy way to do this could be use the replace method
 query = query.Replace("'", "'''")